# Ramdom failure on https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token request

Tags: community, rest-api, oauth2

I am connecting with the Salesforce API using OAuth, refresh_token, client_id & client_secret.

API calls are failing randomly with, it's not every API call but 1 in 100 or sometime in 1000 will fail with `invalid_grant: authentication failure`. Below is the example of the request I am doing to salesforce.

```
curl -X POST \
 https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token \
 -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 -d 'grant_type=refresh_token
     &refresh_token=our_refresh_token
     &client_id=client_id
     &client_secret=client_secret'
```

The solution I tried but didn't work:-

- Creating a new refresh_token.
- Relaxing API limit for the app.

Some more information on the issue:-

- This bug started coming out of nowhere after we migrated our Salesforce instance to custom URL e.g:- `myorg.my.salesforce.com`, could there be an issue because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found out we were running out of our API credits, though `/auth/token` isn't counted as API request but just reducing the API calls fixed it for us.